# Pause a screen terminal

Tags: command-line, suspend, session, r

I constantly use terminal screens to manage different tasks in linux. I would like to know if is possible to 'pause' or 'suspend' a given screen and resume it later (no reboot in between).

Let's say that I create the following screen:

```
screen -S R
```

Then I start R and let a process running:

```
for(lop in 1:1000000){
print(lop)}
```

There is a way to say something like:

```
screen -X -S R pause
```

And resume afterwards wit something like:

```
 screen -X -S R pause
```

My whole point is to release some processing power temporarily without killing long processes. I would be glad for any light here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you started `screen` with `screen -S R`, you initially started with a shell inside the screen session, probably bash. So, you could take advantage of bash's job management by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to suspend the R process, and then resume it later with `fg`:

```
[1] 7221
[1] 7222
[1] 7223
[1] 7224
^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 R

$ fg
[1] 7225
```

Comment: The same can be achieved by using `kill -s 19 <processid>` to pause a process (Sends a SIGSTOP which is the same as the Ctrl+Z shortcut) and `kill -s 18 <pid>` to resume it (Sends a SIGCONT which is the same as typing `fg`).